# How to Create DropdownList with CheckBox in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, dropdownbox

I am new to WPF. I wan to create a Dropdown List which will contain CheckBox items in to it as show in image. Is it Possible?

[image]

Comment: [Working with Checkboxes in the WPF TreeView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the perfect solution to your question, but maybe it helps you anyway.
(You don't have to use `<Canvas>` but i like it because it's more comfortable to place elements)

```
<Canvas>
    <ListBox Canvas.Left="280" Canvas.Top="40" Width="170">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TreeView>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Outboard">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Generic">
                        <CheckBox>Bronze</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox>Clear</CheckBox>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Guardian">
                        <CheckBox>Clear</CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox>UltraWhite</CheckBox>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeView>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Canvas>
```

Sry can't post a picture yet because i don't have enough Reputations.
So i uploaded it.

http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/849/examplezt.png

I used a Listbox instead of a Combobox and you only can check the latest items.

Comment: hi, it's work but just for child item. How to add checkbox to parent item?